# GUESSING radiation from an accelerated charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

The radiation by a non-relativistic accelerated moving charge is given by the Larmor's formula $$P=\frac{2q^2a^3}{3c^3}$$ (in Gaussian units). Now is there any way to answer the following questions without using the above formula and just from purely physical considerations:-

1. Is $P$ proportional to $q$ or $q^2$ ?
2. Is $P$ proportional to  $v$ , $v^2$ , $a$ or $a^2$ ?

Comment: It must be proportional to $q^2$ because negative charges radiate too. (Proportional to $q$ would mean negative charges suck in energy.) It can't be proportional to $v$ or  $v^2$ because charges in uniform motion don't radiate. It can't be proportional to an odd power of $a$ because that would mean a charge accelerating to the left sucks in energy, so it's $a^2$.

Comment: Good arguments!

Comment: @knzhou: that should be an answer!